# how to change CupertinoDatePicker /Month name / to Month number flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to change  CupertinoDatePicker /Month name / to Month number flutter ? and Is it possible to change the place of months and days?
I do not want to add any package
thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2):

use parameter dateOrder:

```
 dateOrder:DatePickerDateOrder.dmy
```

Comment: Thank you , what about change to month number?

Comment: https://codesinsider.com/flutter-cupertino-date-time-picker-example/